out of gas: not enough gas for reentrancy sentry
I am getting "out of gas: not enough gas for reentrancy sentry".   I am trying to send a bunch of micro txns at once from different wallets if that helps with context.
Here is the txn:
https://basescan.org/vmtrace?txhash=0x6d317820ae92b50c92a84e5a64ed9b19d904278d87a1bfae1fd247ba003b7f56&type=gethtrace2
I have no idea what this means and cannot find any information on it.

Probably gas limit was too low

Thanks @0xSanson.  I messaged you on discord if you have time to check it
